# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:[com.weshopify.platform.WeshopifyUserManagement

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, boot

[error file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzWNn.png)
[controller layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1iBk.png)[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rAuo.png)

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spDRY.png)

[application.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7PbG.png)

[entity class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkP3q.png)

Hi, when I am trying to run spring boot application I have getting this errors and I checked multiple times .
could you help me for resolving this problem.

Comment: don't post pictures, post the actual code instead

Comment: There is far too little information in this question, the information that is available is in clickable links to images which not provide the needed information. We need at least the code (as code not images) and the **full stacktrace** to be able to answer this.